# Claims-based Authentication with Username/Password OR Client Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

I am beginning a project to build a web site/web service which will be used by people logging in via a browser with username/password but the same site will be accessed by a device.  The device will use client certificates to authenticate with the service.

This will be built using Web API/MVC4 and will be using Claims-based Authentication (and eventually Authorization, too).  I am comfortable with using Claims-based authentication to authenticate a user logging in, and I think I have a good grasp of using a client certificate to authenticate a device accessing the service.

My question revolves around being able to support both types of authentication in the same site.  The user would login when navigating to: http://product.site.com/manage and the device would be making requests to: http://product.site.com/updates.  I haven't had a chance to get into coding this yet but I expect that I'm going to end up with conflicting authentications.  For example, when a device makes a request the username/password auth is going to try to authenticate the user and it will never make it to the client certificate validation.

I have a feeling that I may end up having to host 2 separate sites, one for the web site and a second for the services used by devices so that each can be configured separately for authentication.

Does anybody have any experience implementing something like this, or suggestions?

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement it? I have exactly the same scenario and any lead would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In the end I didn't need to implement a solution to this problem. It was a very new project and the requirements changed before I ever got to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in the webapi part you can use messagehandler. You can have a message handler for both the username password auth and the cert, which sets the currentprincipal when auth succeeds

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply! I presume it is C# / ASP.Net specific solution, isn't it? I am coming from the JAva world... I thought there was a general solution that not relating to a specific programming language. Anyway thanks for your effort!